# How to install PHP 5.5.12 (specific version) and mysql 5.6.17 on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, php

How can I install PHP 5.5.12 (specific version) and mysql 5.6.17 on Ubuntu 15.04? There are ways to install LAMP, but I am looking for the specific versions. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

LAMP, Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP... as package doesnt have the newest releases of everything. Im sure someday there will be a LAMP package with php5.6 but not currently evidently. So that puts you with installing LAMP packages individually from source, or add a repo that includes php5.6.

You can try [this page](http://phpave.com/upgrade-to-php-56-on-ubuntu-1404-lts/) for installing php5.6.

Comment: Could you please provide the steps in install the packages individually

Answer (score 1):

For older versions of MySQL you would go to:

[MySQL Community Version](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/)

And for PHP you would go to
[php.net/releases](http://php.net/releases/)

Comment: Could you please provide the steps in install the packages individually

Comment: Usually there is a README or INSTALL file when you download the software, and from there you will be able to install it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably download them from somewhere (using Google or your favorite search engine) as .deb packages and install them with `sudo dpkg -i /path_to_the_downloaded_package/package_name.deb`.

Another option is to compile them directly from their source code.

Comment: Could you please provide the steps in install the packages individually